# Flow action input doesn't recognize apex defined type

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I've 2 flow actions `Create Folder` and `Get Resource Property`. `Create Folder` returns an apex defined type `Resource`. `Get Resource Property` expects a parameter of type `Resource`, however when I pass the output of `Create Folder` to `Get Resource Property`, flow complains about it.

Here is the skeleton on both actions

```
//Create Folder
global with sharing class CreateFolder {
  @InvocableMethod(
    label='Create Folder'
    callout=true
  )
  global static List<Resource> execute(List<FlowInput> inputs) {
    List<Resource> response = List<Resource>();
    // code here
    return response;
  }

  global class FlowInput {
   // inputs
  }
}
```

```
//Get Resource Property
global with sharing class GetResourceProperty {
  @InvocableMethod(
    label='Get Resource Property'
  )
  global static List<String> execute(List<FlowInput> inputs) {
   // code here
  }

  global class FlowInput {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Resource')
    global Resource resource;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Property Name')
    global String name;
  }
}
```

```
// Type - Resource
global class Resource {
  @InvocableVariable(label='Resource Id')
  @AuraEnabled
  global String id;

  @InvocableVariable(label='Resource Name')
  @AuraEnabled
  global String name;
}
```

Flow
[image]

Error
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems with your wrapper, you are using a nested wrapper

```
  global class FlowInput {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Resource')
    global Resource resource;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Property Name')
    global String name;
}
```

This Resource variable is then an instance another class altogether I don't think flow a declarative tool can resolve this level of nesting of class, properties,etc.

you can try this out

```
global class FlowInput {   @InvocableVariable(label='Resource Id')  
  @AuraEnabled   global String id;

  @InvocableVariable(label='Resource Name')   @AuraEnabled   global
  String resourceName;

  @InvocableVariable(label='Property Name')
  global String propertyName;   }
```

then instead of this
[image]

you will see both the properties

Flow is a declarative tool comes with its set of limitations, your wrapper class might have easily worked with Aura or LWC

the apex defined type for you is FlowInput Class which it is easily recognising but the nested apex defined type resource is not supported